# Matrix representation of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $a:\,\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear operator (i.e. $a$ is a linear operator in each component).

Then exists a square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it holds

$a(u,v)=v^tAu$?

where $v^t$ is the transpose of the column vector $v$.

Comment: That's correct. What is the question?

Comment: If you're interested in seeing why that is the case, then consider $u$ and $v$ written as linear combinations of the standard bases and use the bilinearity of $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ to see what $A$ is. If you do it right, it will be $A = (A_{ij})$, where $A_{ij} = a(e_i,e_j)$.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. What happens is that I have an awful bilinear form which I would rewritte in that form, and I wanted to know, in advanced, if this was possible.

Thanks again :)

Comment: @yemino It is in fact possible. If you want to compute it, my hint will lead you to $A_ij = a(\cdot, \cdot)$ for some special vectors ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $e_i$ is standard basis. Then what is $a(e_i,e_j)$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
Write $u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i e_i, v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$ and use bilinearity of $a$ on
$$a(u,v)$$
Now compare this to
$$v^T A u$$
This should give you an idea how $A$ looks like.